# Custom Spinner View (Don't want a pop-up spinner)

Tags: android

I would like to create a custom spinner view so that the spinner options are displayed directly below the spinner control, NOT in a modal pop-up.  I would like it to be modeless and the functionality would be similar to what you might see in an html select tag.  I'm using Android platform 2.1.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [`Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#MODE_DROPDOWN)? I'm pretty sure you can also set it from xml. This should do exactly what you're looking for, however, in my experience not all devices respect the flag. Nevertheless you might want to dive into the `Spinner`s implementation for more clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be technically possible, but it's not going to be worth it.  I know it is a terrible answer, but I don't think it's wise to fight the system on basic UI controls if you don't have to.  You would likely be going to a path from which you are unlikely to emerge in victory.  It's more than a quick stackoverflow answer.

Are you getting design requirements like this from someone else?  If so, please have them read through [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) if you need to push back.  What is the main reason you *want* this html-like behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I think I was just not thinking clearly.  I think I realized what I really want is something similar to a ListView and not a Spinner.